# Difference between super and ((parent)this)?

Tags: java

Super keyword related doubt.

```
class Parent{
    int x=40;
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{   int x=20;
    void show()      //method overriding has been done
    {

        System.out.println(super.x); // prints parent data member
        System.out.println(((Parent)this).x); /*same output as previous statement which means super is similar to (Parent)this*/ 
        System.out.println("child");
        super.show();  // invokes parent show() method  
        ((Parent)this).show(); //Doesnt invoke parent show() method.Why?
    }

public static void main(String s[])
{ 
    Child c1=new Child(); //Child class object
    c1.show();  
}}
```

So, `System.out.println(super.x)` and `System.out.println(((Parent)this).x)` prints the same value.So if `super.show()` calls parent class `show()` method then why is `((Parent)this).show();` unable to call parent `show()`? Please tell appropriate explaination for this.

Comment: You should probably fix the indentation of your code, then someone will answer your question.

Comment: what's the point of casting the `this` pointer to the super class if you can just call the method (because it is defined in the parent), so you can just use `this.show();`, `super.show()` or just `show()` !? unless you have overridden the `show`method in your child class then super.show() calls the parent instead of the local one.

Comment: `((Base)this).show(); //Doesnt invokes parent show() method.Why?`.. what  is `Base`? it should be `((Parent)this).show()`

Comment: You call to `((Parent) this).show(); ` (I think this was what you intended) inside `Child.show()` still hits `Child.show()`, so it’s a recursive call (leading to infinite recursion). I think this answers your question.

Comment: "Doesnt invoke parent show() method.Why?" For the same reason that invoking this: `Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(0); System.out.println(((Object) integer).toString());` doesn't invoke `Object.toString()`.

Comment: Sorry, right I intended to write ((Parent)this).show();

Comment: Ole V.V. , I do agree, its leading to infinite recursion but super is similar to ((Parent)this) in particular code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `((Parent) this).show();` on what is really a `Child` object causes `Child.show()` to be called. Whether you are doing it as `myObject.show()` or through `this` makes no difference for which version of the method gets called — it’s always the method determined by the object’s runtime type, in this case `Child`.

So you have a recursive call, leading to infinite recursion.

`super.show()` on the other hand calls the method in the super class, in this case `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

**Constructor Chaining**
in Java keyword `this` represent current object and when one class extends another then its super class reference variable may hold child class reference variable  that's is in your code is `((Parent)this).x` ,

while `super` keyword is used to call directly super class constructor and its variables.

at the same time when `super` class variables holds child class object and when we use super it refers  same object .

> How to call one constructor from another constructor in Java or What
>   is Constructor Chaining in Java is one of the tricky questions in Java
>   interviews. Well, you can use this keyword to call one constructor
>   from another constructor of the same class if you want to call a
>   constructor from based class or super class then you can use super
>   keyword. Calling one constructor from other is called Constructor
>   chaining in Java. Constructors can call each other automatically or
>   explicitly using this() and super() keywords. this() denotes a
>   no-argument constructor of the same class and super() denotes a no
>   argument or default constructor of parent class. Also having multiple
>   constructors in the same class is known as constructor overloading in
>   Java.

Read more: http://www.java67.com/2012/12/how-constructor-chaining-works-in-java.html#ixzz4bJ5C069o